# Using boto3 to retrieve a SG rule Description

Tags: python, boto

We are trying to use boto3 to query our AWS instances and get all security groups which have rules with no description.  I have not been able to figure out how to retrieve the Rule description.  I have included an image of the column I want to retrieve below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share the solution I came up with late in the evening, piecing together bits from other solutions - primarily from @Abdul Gill and hist ec2_sg_rules script.

```
import boto3

# Explicitly declaring variables here grants them global scope
cidr_block = ""
ip_protpcol = ""
from_port = ""
to_port = ""
from_source = ""
description = ""
sg_filter = [{'Name': 'group-name', 'Values': ['*ssh*']}]

print("%s,%s,%s" % ("Group-Name","Group-ID","CidrIp"))

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2' )
sgs = ec2.describe_security_groups(Filters=sg_filter)["SecurityGroups"]
for sg in sgs:
    group_name = sg['GroupName']
    group_id = sg['GroupId']
    # print("%s,%s" % (group_name,group_id))
    # InBound permissions ##########################################
    inbound = sg['IpPermissions']

    for rule in inbound:

        #Is source/target an IP v4?
        if len(rule['IpRanges']) > 0:
            for ip_range in rule['IpRanges']:
                cidr_block = ip_range['CidrIp']
                if 'Description' not in ip_range:
                    if '10.' not in cidr_block:
                        print("%s,%s,%s" % (group_name, group_id, cidr_block))
    print('\n')
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.